# How can I apply fisher test on this set of data (nominal variables)

Tags: r, testing, statistics

I'm pretty new in statistics:

```
fisher = function(idxToTest, idxATI){

idxDependent=c()
dependent=c()
p = c()

for(i in c(1:length(idxToTest)))
{
    tbl = table(data[[idxToTest[i]]], data[[idxATI]])
    rez = fisher.test(tbl, workspace = 20000000000)
    if(rez$p.value<0.1){
        dependent=c(dependent, TRUE)
        if(rez$p.value<0.1){
            idxDependent = c(idxDependent, idxToTest[i])
        }
    }
    else{
        dependent = c(dependent, FALSE)
    }
    p = c(p, rez$p.value)
}

}
```

This is the function I use. It seems to work.

What I understood until now is that I have to pass as first parameter data like:

```
                Men    Women 
Dieting         10      30 
Non-dieting     5       60
```

My data comes from a CSV:

```
data = read.csv('***.csv', header = TRUE, sep=',');
```

My first problem is that I don't know how to converse from:

```
Loan.Purpose   Home.Ownership
lp_value_1     ho_value_2
lp_value_1     ho_value_2
lp_value_2     ho_value_1
lp_value_3     ho_value_2
lp_value_2     ho_value_3
lp_value_4     ho_value_2
lp_value_3     ho_value_3
```

to:

```
              ho_value_1    ho_value_2    ho_value_3
lp_value1     0             2             0
lp_value2     1             0             1
lp_value3     0             1             1
lp_value4     0             1             0
```

The second issue is that I don't know what the second parameter should be

**POST UPDATE:** This is what I get using `fisher.test(myTable)`:

```
Error in fisher.test(test) : FEXACT error 501.
The hash table key cannot be computed because the largest key
is larger than the largest representable int.
The algorithm cannot proceed.
Reduce the workspace size or use another algorithm.
```

where `myTable` is:

```
           MORTGAGE NONE OTHER OWN RENT
  car                      18    0     0   5   27
  credit_card             190    0     2  38  214
  debt_consolidation      620    0     2  87  598
  educational               5    0     0   3    7
  ...
```

Comment: have you tried `table(Loan.Purpose,Home.Ownership)`?

Comment: why don't you use `fisher.test()`?

Comment: @Seth - ok the table line seems to work now I get the correct table data at print but I get a new error. check post update

Comment: I'm not sure how that function works, but you can convert the table to, e.g., a matrix with `as.matrix(your_table)` if that's what the function expects.

Comment: It appears you are out of memory and cannot run the exact test. Have you considered `chisq.test()`?

Comment: Also, the `workspace = 20000000000` part should be appropriately chosen for the particular computer you are using.

Comment: @Frank - thanks for the suggestion but `as.matrix` doesn't change the table: it outputs the same result.. this is how I'm using it: `test = table(data$Loan.Purpose, data$Home.Ownership)
print(test)
test2 = as.matrix(test)
print(test2)`

Comment: @Seth - it seams that `chisq.test` is working.. is there a way to put this tests into a graph of any type?

Comment: I would do `mosaicplot(Loan.Purpose,Home.Ownership)`

Comment: @Seth - I think I'll stick with `chisq.test`.. please post your answer for upvote/accept.. some extra info on how to read those values could be great.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, fisher tests only work on smallish data sets because they require alot of memory. But all is good because chi-square tests make minimal additional assumptions and are easier on the computer. Just do:

```
chisq.test(Loan.Purpose,Home.Ownership)
```

to get your p-values.

Make sure you read through and understand the help page for chisq.test, especially the examples at the bottom.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/chisq.test.html

Then look at a mosaicplot to see the quantities like:

```
 mosaicplot(Loan.Purpose,Home.Ownership)
```

this reference explains how mosaicplots work.

http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~tpminka/courses/36-350.2001/lectures/day12/